# Hide ad in Youtube frame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

Is it possible to hide elements in third-party iframe? As example — YT player by iframe_api and their ads. I tried to get iframe content `document` or `contentDocument` but browser blocked me. 
May be some tricks exists? Example — [awsmtv.com](https://awsmtv.com)

Comment: No, that is not possible. The Same Origin Policy prevents you from interacting with iframed content from a different domain via client-side scripting. Plus, you would likely be violating YouTube’s terms of service, if you hid their ads.

Comment: @CBroe but this guys do it — [awsmtv](https://awsmtv.com/)

Comment: I don't think that is Youtube...

Comment: @Adjit they call youtube api by iframe_api and YT.player in resources.